# Smooth rotation

Tags: xna, c#, rotation, monogame

I would like to rotate my Player very smooth. At the moment the player stops rotating when I release the button. Also the rotation should get faster, if the player rotates longer. I use XNA and have no idea how to solve this.

Sry for my english, I hope you understand what I mean.

Michi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
float turnSpeed;
if (KeyBoard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    turnSpeed++;
if (KeyBoard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    turnSpeed--;

 RotationAngle += turnSpeed;
 //Adjust what you multiplay turnSpeed for how long you want him to stay spinning.
 turnSpeed *= 0.89f;
```

He should now speed up while turning, then when you release the turning keys on the keyboard he should spin a tiny bit then stop.

Comment: Now the rotation is smooth, although he doesn't speed up...

Comment: This code initializes a new variable called turnSpeed each update, meaning it never changes in magnitude because it is always initialized to its default value each time. You need to use a variable that maintains an appropriate scope for your rotational velocity.